# OO C++ - Virtual Methods

Tags: c++, oop

Just a really quick question here. I'm using virtual functions to read in from a text file. Now, it's virtual because in one aspect I want the values to be normalised, and, in the other respect I don't want them to be normalised. I have tried to do this:

```
bool readwav(string theFile, 'native');
```

So in theory, if the 'native' is used, this method should be called, however, if 'double' is called then a different version of the method is called. Same for if the value is empty, it should just perform the native option.

First question, why doesn't the declaration above work? Also, is this the best route to go down? Or, would it be better to have just one class method that switches between the options.

Thanks :)

Update:

Where am I going wrong?

```
bool Wav::readwav(string theFile, ReadType type = NATIVE)
{
// Attempt to open the .wav file
ifstream file (theFile.c_str());

if(!this->readHeader(file))
{
    cerr << "Cannot read header file";
    return 0;
}

for(unsigned i=0; (i < this->dataSize); i++)
{
    float c = (unsigned)(unsigned char)data[i];

    this->rawData.push_back(c);
}

return true;
}

bool Wav::readwav(string theFile, ReadType type = DOUBLE)
{
  // Attempt to open the .wav file
  ifstream file (theFile.c_str());

  cout << "This is the double information";
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: "Or, would it be better to have just one class method that switches between the options" - this. C++ is not functional programming language with pattern-matching ;)

Comment: 1) What is 'native'? In c++ an argument declaration should have a type. 2) Why should parameter value affect virtual function being called? It's affected by the actual type of `this` only.

Comment: @Phorce - You're misunderstanding the default parameter I mentioned in my answer. This only appears in the function declaration, not the definition as you have here. It means that if you don't provide a ReadType argument, it will default to NATIVE.

Comment: @Aesthete I'm really confused. Using the enum, how do I differentiate between native and double? In a sense that, I don't want it always to be native, I want it to be double aha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is an enumeration with a default parameter.

```
enum FileType
{
  NATIVE=0,
  DOUBLE      
};

bool readwav(string theFile, FileType type = NATIVE);
```

Default parameters are present in the function **declaration**, do not put them in the **definition**.

```
bool readwav(string theFile, FileType type)
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case NATIVE: { ... } break;
    case DOUBLE: { ... } break;
    default: { ... } break;
  }
}
```

This way, calling `readwav` without a parameter will use the `NATIVE` type by default.

```
readwav("myfile.wav"); // Uses NATIVE type
readwav("myfile.wav", NATIVE); // Also uses NATIVE
readwav("myfile.wav", DOUBLE); // Uses DOUBLE type
```

Comment: in my .cpp function implementation, I need to switch "type" incase it's native or double?

Comment: Gotcha now :) But it would be "0" or "1", right? 0 = native 1 = double! Thank you so much! Sorry I've been a pain haha

Comment: It's all good man, I'm glad it works. Make sure you take into account all the answers here, they are all right. But no, you just use the enumeration like `NATIVE`, you don't have switch by the associated numbers, it's all done for you at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Because `'native'` is a multi-char character, not a string. I'd go with multiple versions of the function though:

```
bool readwavNative(string theFile);
bool readwavDouble(string theFile);
```

or at least an `enum` as the second parameter:

```
enum ReadType
{
   ReadNative,
   ReadDouble
};

//...
bool readwav(string theFile, ReadType type);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm confused about the enum and the function in my .cpp file, can I still declare multiple functions etc..?

Comment: all caps is usually reserved for macros.

Comment: @Phorce did you have multiple functions in your original code?

Comment: I always use capitals for enumerations, and haven't met many people who don't.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Hey, could you have a look at my original post and tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: @Phorce you're defining the same function twice. It should be just one  `bool Wav::readwav(string theFile, ReadType type)` and have an `if` inside - `if ( type == ReadDouble )... else if (type == ReadNative) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The question has oop in it so I would assume an oop answer is wanted. I think a [strategy patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would suit your purpose.

```
class WavReader
{
public:
    WavReader(const std::string fileName)
    {
        //open file and prepare to read
    }

    virtual ~WavReader()
    {
        //close file
    }

    virtual bool read()=0;
};

class NativeWavReader: public WavReader
{
public:
    NativeWavReader(const std::string fileName): WavReader(fileName){}

    virtual bool read()
    {
        //native reading method
        std::cout<<"reading\n";
        return true;
    }
};
```

`NativeWavReader` implements the `read` method from the strategy `WavReader`, if you want another method you create a class `OtherWavReader` reading the file differently.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I don't really want to implement another class to read in the file, just simply have a virtual function that changes depending on if 'Native' or 'Double' is implemented. :)

Comment: @Phorce In that case I miss-understood the question. Then I would follow Luchian Grigore's suggestion.

Comment: @Phorce - I don't think you quite understand the purpose of virtual functions. Virtual methods without multiple classes are useless.

Comment: @Aesthete I do have multiple classes, just, I don't want a separate class for parsing the data :)!

Comment: @Phorce I don't know what other classes you have but you could connect them to the reading strategy by using a bridge pattern. I'm sorry that I'm that fussy but function switching feels just so non-oop.